# Can not update project on Intellij

Tags: git, intellij-idea

When I click on "Git update project" on the top right corner, I get "Can't Update, No tracked branch configured for branch master or the branch doesn't exist." But on the terminal everything looks ok.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Commit and push they also work fine.

Comment: can you please screenshot of intellij idea about what you are clicking on. I don't see such option in my intellij.. And also share version of intellij

Comment: @VinayPrajapati, updated the question.

Answer (score 4):

The Update project action updates all repositories present in the project. Looks like there is more than one, and one of them fails. Check the Console tab of the Version Control toolwindow for more details.

If you have the **Execute branch operations on all roots** turned on, the entire Update project process fails when updating any of the repositories fail, to prevent diverging.

Comment: Hi, thank you. The console tab of VCS is already in the screenshot, there is no more info. 
I have only one repository. I can not even find the "Execute branch....all roots".
I googled and found it should be in "Settings | Version Control | Git | Control branches from different roots synchronously." but nothing there.

Comment: The screenshot shows Event log and Terminal, no Console tab of VCS. Open Version Control Toolwindow (Cmd/Alt+9) and look for the Console tab. it will show you what exact command and in what exact root has failed.

Comment: You could also submit an issue to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with IDE logs attached to investigate

Comment: View/Tools Window/Version Control. The tabs I see are Local changes and Log. I googled it since your first post and found this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/version-control-tool-window-console-tab.html
But it's not there in my intellij. Will look into it.

Comment: Hi again, the console appeared when I clicked on the "cherry pick" icon. 
When I click on update project no related command is mentioned in the console. Only the cherry pick related from before.
git -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false cherry-pick -x -n e808c0ba894e04049464d096a53fdb73633537db